# AWS lambda function delete files from S3 folder

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I import some data from Funnel to S3 bucket. After that, Lambda function copy data to table in Redshift and I tried to delete all copied object from bucket folder but I keep getting timeout.

This is my code:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const {Pool} = require('pg');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

async function emptyS3Directory(bucket, dir) {
    const listParams = {
    Bucket: bucket,
     Prefix: dir
    };
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    s3.listObjectsV2(listParams, function(err, data)  // Here I always getting timeout{
    });
.....
}
```

EDIT....
This is code of the function.

```
async function DeleteAllDataFromDir(bucket, dir) {

const listParams = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Prefix: dir
};
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

 const listedObjects = await s3.listObjects(listParams).promise();
 console.log("reponse", listedObjects);
    if (listedObjects.Contents.length === 0) return;

    const deleteParams = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Delete: { Objects: [] }
    };

    listedObjects.Contents.forEach(({ Key }) => {
        deleteParams.Delete.Objects.push({ Key });
    });

    await s3.deleteObjects(deleteParams).promise();

    if (listedObjects.IsTruncated) await DeleteAllDataFromDir(bucket, dir);
}
```

The first time I set the time out to 2 minutes, then I changed it to 10 minutes and I get the same error::

```
{
    "errorType": "NetworkingError",
    "errorMessage": "connect ETIMEDOUT IP:port",
    "code": "NetworkingError",
    "message": "connect ETIMEDOUT IP:port",
    "errno": "ETIMEDOUT",
    "syscall": "connect",
    "address": "IP",
    "port": port,
    "region": "eu-west-2",
    "hostname": "hostName",
    "retryable": true,
    "time": "2020-12-10T08:36:29.984Z",
    "stack": [
        "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.95.148.74:443",
        "    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What did you configure as timeout for your Lambda? What is the value of `err`? Anything in CloudWatch that could give us some more insight?

Comment: shouldn't it be listObjects instead of listObjectsV2?

Comment: @Nonik There is actually such a function/property: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property

Comment: also, since your method is async, you can just simply do const response = await s3.listObjectsV2(listParams).promise(); and make sure your prefix is correct

Comment: Is your AWS Lambda function configured to use a VPC? (Hint: It is better _not_ to connect to a VPC.)

Comment: @ jens timeout is set to 2 minutes and I don't see the error value. Now I have changed the function a bit, but I still have the same error.
@Nonik I tried both.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your bucket may reside in a different region than your lambda function based on the nature of the error.

Provide the [region hash](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#constructor_details) as an option when constructing your S3 client.

```js
var s3 = new AWS.S3({region: 'bucket-region-hash'});
```

To figure the region hash, go to S3 Management Console.
Then from the sidebar, click "Buckets". In the resulting view, you'll find the region hash. It's the one marked in gold as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: I tried and I get the same error. Should I set any special rights to s3 or lambda?